# CodeChef Small factorial Solution

Tags: c

When I ran this code why is it giving me incorrect output?
In my system I'm getting the correct output. In the image first line is the number test case and followed by input and output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    double fact;
    int k,i,m,n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i=n; i>0; i--)
    {
        fact=1;
        scanf("%d", &m);
        for(k=2; k<=m; k++)
            fact *= k;
        printf("%.0lf\n", fact);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example input and output:

[image]

Comment: Please take a look at how to post a [mcve] and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help us assist you further. Where is your example input that demonstrates the problem? What is the output on CodeChef, and what is your expected output?

Comment: You get correct answers for the shown examples. `int` can hold only factorials up to 12; `long long` can hold factorials up to 20. You need to be able to calculate factorials up to 100!, which has 157 digits. This is a coding exercise, you will have to get out your grade school textbook on multiplication and multiply an array of digits by hand. (Alternatively, use a language that supports bignums natively, such as Python.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as M Oehm has pointed out in the comments, is with the data type that you are using for fact.  It is too small to store the factorial of numbers like 100, which contain around 157 digits.  You need to use an array to store the digits.  Here is my approach to the problem (which has has been accepted by the judge).

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int t,j;
   scanf("%d",&t);
   while(t--)
   {
     int n;
     scanf("%d",&n);
     int a[1000] = {1};
     int m = 0;
     int carry = 0;
     for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
     {
       for(j=0; j<=m; j++)
       {
         a[j] = (a[j]*i)+carry;
         carry = a[j]/10;
         a[j] = a[j]%10;
       }
       while(carry)
       {
         m++;
         a[m] = carry%10;
         carry/=10;
       }
     }

     for(int i=m; i>=0; i--)
        printf("%d",a[i]);
     printf("\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**Edit**: The original code that I had posted was in C++; but since the question has been tagged C, I have edited the above code for C.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

the issue is you are using double to store the output of the factorial which is going to be long-range. Just convert the output to BigInteger.for this first cast to string and then to bigint .

```
/* package codechef; // don't place package name! */
    
    import java.util.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.math.BigInteger;
    
    /* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
    class Main
    {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            int t=sc.nextInt();
            if(t>=1 && t<=100) {
                while(t>=1) {
                    int n=sc.nextInt();
                    if(n>=1 && n<=100) {
                    BigInteger f=BigInteger.ONE;
                    while(n>1) {
                        f=f.multiply((new BigInteger (String.valueOf(n))));
                        n--;
                    }
                    System.out.println(f);
                    }
                    t--;
                
                }
            }
            sc.close();
        }   
    }
    //this code is accepted
```